# ProxySettingsPerUser resets to 0 on restart Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, proxy, windows-registry

I've had an issue with the Win 10 settings menu recently, that it would not allow me to change proxy settings. Every time I set it to `Automatically detect settings` it would just change it back to `Use setup script` and my loopback IP as a script address. This caused me issues with various browsers, but changing the `ProxySettingsPerUser` key to 1 from 0 in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` seemed to do the trick. Unfortunately this key seems to be reset to 0 every time I restart my PC, so I have to change it back every time.

Before I try something like removing write permissions from SYSTEM (which I saw recommended on different threads), I'd like to know if there is a better way of going about this, maybe running a .reg script at startup, or changing some other setting.

Any help is appreciated.

Forgot to clarify, I've checked for malware already using Malwarebytes.

Comment: Is this a domain-joined machine where group policy could have been applied? I've seen this happen with proxy software for example which would overwrite these settings.

Comment: @BenLavender No, I wouldn't say so, this is my personal computer at home using a local admin account and I'm not signed into any school or company email (if I understood the definition of domain-joined correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance I’d use something like Process Monitor to see what is overwriting the setting. On my machine (W10 Build 19042) whenever I made the change manually using the Windows 10 settings, it was made to HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\AutoConfigURL by the WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service. Might be worth monitoring that reg path yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure I could use Process Monitor when the OS starts, unless I missed something like that.

Comment: After some digging I found out about "boot logging" which helped me in my case. For fututre reference I found this article useful (point 4 specifically): https://betanews.com/2015/11/18/how-to-monitor-registry-changes/